# Maximum update depth exceeded when I want to remove item from cart

Tags: reactjs

I have problem with getting products form localStroage. I use useEffect to fetch all products in my localStorage

```
useEffect(() => {
  setItemsInCart(getItemFromCart())
}, [itemsInCart])
```

getItemFromCart is function in my cartHelper component :

```
export const getItemFromCart = () =>{
    if(typeof window !== 'undefined'){
      if(localStorage.getItem('cart')){
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'))
      }else{
        return []
      }
    }
}
```

then I map through all items in cart :

```
const showCartProducts = (itemsInCart) => {
    return (
        <div>
          {itemsInCart.map((product,index)=>{
            return(
              <div>
            <Card
              key={index}
              product={product}
              showAddToCartButton={false}
              showQuantityInput={true}
              removeFromCartButton={true}
                    />
              </div>
            )
          })}
        </div>
    );
};
```

And this work fine everything works , but when I want to run onclick function to remove button in my Card component then I get this error

"Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render."

Here is my Card component responsible for removingItem

```
const removeButton = () =>{
     return (

      removeFromCartButton && (
          <button
              onClick={() => removeItem(product._id)}
              className="btn btn-outline-danger mt-2 mb-2"
          >
              Remove Product
          </button>
      )
    );
};
```

and removeItem function form my cardHelper :

```
export const removeItem = productId => {
     let cart = [];
       if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
         if (localStorage.getItem("cart")) {
          cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
      }

      cart.map((product, i) => {
          if (product._id === productId) {
              cart.splice(i, 1);
          }
      });

      localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart));
     }
     return cart;
};
```

I don't know how to solve this , please help me :).

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the below code

```
useEffect(() => {
  setItemsInCart(getItemFromCart())
}, [itemsInCart])
```

Whenever you change `itemsInCart` it will be called and inside you are again changing  `itemsInCart` it's like an infinite loop going on.

You can change it to if you want to fetch from local storage to happen only once.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setItemsInCart(getItemFromCart())
}, []) // empty dependency array.
```

For Removing item, you can update `itemsInCart` at the function by resetting it or by removing the item from `itemsInCart` as well.

Resetting the new value

```
export const removeItem = productId => {
     let cart = [];
       if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
         if (localStorage.getItem("cart")) {
          cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
      }

      cart.map((product, i) => {
          if (product._id === productId) {
              cart.splice(i, 1);
          }
      });

      localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart));
     }
     setItemsInCart(cart);
     return cart;
};
```

Or update by delete instead of above change.

```
setItemsInCart([...itemsInCart.filter(it => it._id !== productId)]);
```

Comment: Okey, then when I click remove button indeed Item is removed from localstorage, but component dont rerender.

Comment: While removing an item you need to remove from localStorage as well the state where you are setting it i.e itemsInCart

Comment: But the problem is that, all of this code are in different files. getItemFromCart - cardHelper.js, showCartProducts and useEffect - Cart.js, removeButton - Card.js it is reused multiple times. So when I want to do your changes then I got undefined error.

Comment: Can you please add the code in codesandbox having the folder structure you have.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-glade-52lwr.  -  here you have only front-end code.

Comment: Can you add sample products that will be present in local storage Will add manually and check.

Comment: I managed to do it by moving removeButton to Cart component and add onlick with removeItem function where I fire removeItem function from cardHelper component and after that I fetch again products from localstorage and set itemsInCart. It work fine :) Any issus with that kind of solution?